# How do I install missing languages on Manjaro Linux?

Tags: internationalization, manjaro

I need to test i18n with arabic and japanese. neither language seem to be supported on Manjaro/KDE for either firefox or chromium.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like chrome has them listed in English but Firefox has them listed in native language, which is why I didn't find "Arabic" under the A's.